# WP7 Grid Position

Tags: windows-phone-7, grid

I really need help on this, I have a 9x9 grid in WP7, with gridlines. I have a character in each of the grid "cell".

How could I retrieve the position in the grid using [,] or any other means? Hopefully I can get the position through: `grid[col, row]`

I tried using this: `char[,] grid = new char[numColumnsToAdd, numRowsToAdd];`

But it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally recommend to only use grid cells and rows for layout purposes and not to track the current row/cell. But since you are already doing this, I would simply track clicks on each control (e.g. Label) via a single event handler. Then, simply check the row or cell via:

```
object row = ((TextBlock)sender).GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
object cell = ((TextBlock)sender).GetValue(Grid.CellProperty);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I can't actually do it through the event handler.
Cos after i define my 9x9grid, i have to populate it with characters in each grid "cell".

Comment: if (grid[xSel, ySel] != ' ')
{
}

Comment: Is it a Grid control or something else?

Comment: What you are showing cannot be done with the Grid control. For each cell in the grid you need a control that will hold the character (e.g. TextBlock) and then you need to handle the click event (aka touch) for that control.

Comment: okay. thanks. could u take a look at my code then?
do
            {
                int index = generator.Next(words.Count);
                string selWord = words[index];
               
                int xSel = generator.Next(numColumnsToAdd);
                int ySel = generator.Next(numRowsToAdd);
                int dir = generator.Next(2);

Comment: //Try inserting the word into the grid.
                if (dir == 0) //Vertical
                {
                    if ((ySel + selWord.Length) < numRowsToAdd) //Make sure the word fits!
                    {
                        //See if we can fit the word in
                        int cntWordIndex = 0;
                        for (int yIndex = ySel; yIndex < (ySel + selWord.Length); yIndex++)
                        {

Comment: //Can we place this character in this slot?
                            if (grid[xSel, ySel] != ' ' && grid[xSel, ySel] != selWord[cntWordIndex])
                            {
                                validPosition = false;
                                break;
                            }